# Working on Beagleboard with Cloud9 and Github

Tags: git, github, beagleboard, cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack

I just got a Beagle Board and started working with Cloud9. Everything worked fine until I tried to integrate it with Github.

I could git init because I "didn't have sudo permissions" on Cloud9. Therefore, I cloned a repo to use with Cloud9. **Now, however, it looks like the Beagle Board dependencies are no longer there.** I get this error:

[image]

The code I'm trying to run (which gets the error) is:

```
var b = require("bonescript");
b.pinMode('USR0', b.OUTPUT);
b.digitalWrite('USR0', b.HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0):

use npm to install missing dependencies `npm install bonescript`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to check the version and to see if BoneScript is in your path, run:

```
node -pe "require('bonescript').getPlatform().bonescript"
```

Or maybe, your service just stopped....try this (and then reboot to check):

```
systemctl enable bonescript.socket systemctl enable

bonescript-autorun.service
```